# Command to make some (not all) moving turtles stop moving in response to satisfying a condition

Tags: netlogo

Is there a command in netlogo that allows to some (1 or more) and not all (as with the `stop` command) to stop moving mid-simulation in upon satisfying a given condition?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You will get better answers if you provide a minimal working example showing what you are trying to do and how it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luke's answer addresses your specific question, but with the additional information in the comment I think you may want something like:

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [ if random-float 1 < 0.1 [ <move function ]
  ]
end
```

If they are supposed to never move again, then the easiest is to create a variable that stores whether they are finished and do something like:

```
to go
  ask turtles with [!finished?]
  [ if-else random-float 1 < 0.1
    [ <move function ]
    [ set finished? TRUE ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jen. This implementation works as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using `stop` is probably not best for what you're describing- it's a primitive that just exits the current procedure and has no direct relation to turtle behavior other than what you program it to do. Nonetheless, you indeed **can** use stop on individual turtles. Using this setup:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 5 [
    set color green
  ]
  reset-ticks  
end
```

In this simple example, **all** turtles will first check if they are red, and if that is true, they will `stop` and exit the `go-stop` procedure. If it is *not* true, they will complete the procedure.

```
to go-stop 
  ask turtles [
    if color = red [
      stop
    ]
    rt random 60 - 30
    fd 1
    if xcor < -10 [
      set color red
    ]
  ]
end
```

That is fine, but is not as efficient as this example that does *not* use stop; this one only deals with the turtles that are still able to move (because they are green) :

```
to go
  ask turtles with [ color = green ] [
    rt random 60 - 30
    fd 1
    if xcor < -10 [
      set color red
    ]
  ]
end
```

**Edit:**

Try this version, where you use the `turtles-own` variable `allowed-to-move?` as a way to separate turtles that you want to move from those that you want to be stationary. Again, I do not use `stop` because I don't think it's the right way to go about this but if you prefer you can modify the following example to use `stop` as in the example above. Additionally- you say "if that number exceeds a 0.01 for any turtle that turtle should stop moving" but in this example turtles will stop if they select a random number *below* 0.01, because I am using few turtles and otherwise almost all turtles would stop within a tick or two. Anyway, using more or less the same setup as before, but accommodating the new `turtles-own` variable:

```
turtles-own [ allowed-to-move? ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 5 [
    set allowed-to-move? true
  ]
  reset-ticks  
end
```

Now you can just have turtles change their `allowed-to-move?` to `false` whenever the condition you choose is satisfied. In this example, turtles will select a random number between 0 and 1- if that number is less than 0.01, they `set` their `allowed-to-move?` to `false`, which means they will not satisfy the condition `with [ allowed-to-move? ] ...` on the next tick. Therefore, once a turtle has stopped moving it will no longer move.

```
to go
  ask turtles with [ allowed-to-move? ] [
    rt random 60 - 30
    fd 1
    if random-float 1 < 0.01 [
      set allowed-to-move? false
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, in the case where you use `stop` does it stop just the turtles that satisfy the stipulated condition (red (not green) turtles in your example), or does it cause the whole program to stop? Upon testing it, it seems like it caused the whole program to stop. In my code i have many turtles moving in the world and at each step, each turtle selects a random number from 0 to 1, and if that number exceeds a 0.01 for any turtle that turtle should stop moving as part of a stopping procedure that is separate from the moving procedure ... this is what i am going for, any thoughts?

Comment: at the next time step, does the stopped turtle again generate a random number and move if the number is small enough, or does it stop permanently once it has ever had a high random number?

Comment: @JenB Thanks a lot. I do know how to ask stackoverflow questions. I would have posted the code but it has quite a few moving parts and I figured I could struggle condensing it to something workable that still maintains the essence of the question I wanted to ask or I could simply ask the conceptual question and both you and Luke clearly understand my question and have put good answers forth, pending some clarification, which we are working through, so thank you. The answer to your question in your previous comment is that a stopped turtle should stop forever.

Comment: @LukeC what if I do not want stopped turtles to move again?

Comment: @nigus21 Sorry, I was away. To your first question- the `stop` only exits the procedure for the current turtle running that procedure. If you run my example program, you will see that each time `go-stop` is called, ALL green turtles move **every time** the procedure runs. By that same token, once a turtle is red it never moves again- so your most recent question I don't quite understand- when you run my example program, do turtles ever move once they are red? They do not for me. I edit my answer to provide another example that might get closer to what you want.

Comment: @LukeC Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly with your code, my implementation of it in my actual code did not go quite as smoothly but after doing some debugging i realized it was a syntax error on my part, novice-struggles I suppose. I fixed it and it works superbly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nigus21 No problem- and I hear you, that happens to me all the time. Glad you sorted it out!

Comment: @LukeC Hi Luke,hope all is well, I really need your expert thoughts, assistance and advice on the question I posted at the following link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533808/determining-max-min-and-mean-turtle-cluster-size-as-well-as-number-of-turtle-c/46535187#46535187)

Comment: @nigus21 Hello nigus, did Jen's answer to your linked question clear up the issue for you after all?

Comment: @LukeC Hello Luke, it sort of did, unless you know of better ways to identify and perform math operations in turtle clusters in netlogo ...

Comment: @LukeC Hello Luke, are you familiar with the density-based clustering algorithm (dbscan) extension for netlogo? Could you see my comment (the last one) at the following link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475893/determining-the-radius-of-turtle-clusters-and-number-of-turtles-in-them-postpr/46501920#46501920) and let me know your thoughts? I am curious as to how to go beyond just uniquely labeling clusters to performing math operations on them?

Comment: @LukeC I was hoping I can get your advice on a landscape generator code that I am building in NetLogo, would it be possible to set up one of those interactive sessions to discuss?

Comment: @nigus21 - Sorry for the late response. I don't know if you're still working on this problem, but if you are I could try to help. However, I'm fairly busy at the moment and it would probably have to be tonight after 7:00 PM PST.