# Determining the radius of turtle clusters and number of turtles in them - postprocessing

Tags: netlogo

If I have a situation in which about a 1000 black turtles disperse at random angles and steps throughout the netlogo world for a given duration of ticks. Each turtle is assigned a random probability at each timestep during dispersal, and if this number exceeds a given threshold for any given turtle it changes it's color to red and stops moving. Additionally, black turtles (still moving) that happen to move within a patch of red turtles (stopped/settled), change their color to grey and settle (stop moving) as well. Finally, other black turtles (still moving) that happen to be move within a patch of either grey or red turtles (stopped/settled), also change their color to grey and settle (stop moving)

My question is a post-processing question for when the simulation duration is reached. How do I determine the number of clusters of red-grey turtles in the sea of black turtles? Also, how do I determine the size (radial extent) of each cluster? And finally, how do I determine the number of turtles in each cluster?

Comment: This is a design issue - you need to decide how to operationalise what a cluster is. Once you know what you mean by cluster, then we can help you debug as you try to convert that idea into code. Maybe you can do something like look at the density of red-grey turtles per patch and call it a cluster if it is more than x% of the average density and then combine neighbouring patches that are both clusters into the same cluster. But you need to have an algorithm first.

Comment: @JenB thanks, based on the information that you and payette provided, I have rephrased my question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533808/determining-max-min-and-mean-turtle-cluster-size-as-well-as-number-of-turtle-c) Let me know what you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jen is right: you need a clear idea of what constitutes a cluster before being able to truly answer that question.

That being said, one possible option is to use a clustering algorithm. I'd suggest taking a look at Christopher Frantz's [`dbscan` extension](https://github.com/chrfrantz/NetLogo-Extension-DBSCAN).

Here is a quickly thrown together example:

```
extensions [ dbscan ]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
  create-turtles 1000 [
    set color black
    set label-color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask n-of 5 turtles [
    ask turtles in-radius 3 [
      set color one-of [red grey]
    ]
  ]
end

to find-clusters
  let red-grey-turtles turtles with [ member? color [red grey] ]
  let clusters dbscan:cluster-by-location red-grey-turtles 3 3
  (foreach clusters range length clusters [ [c i] ->
    foreach c [ t ->
      ask t [ set label i ]
    ]
  ])
end
```

Sorry for the lack of further explanations: I have a plane to catch...

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I have edited my question to do this without the extension and run into an issue that I think is solvable. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533808/determining-max-min-and-mean-turtle-cluster-size-as-well-as-number-of-turtle-c) and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: this density-based clustering algorithm is awesome, however I was wondering if it can do more than just uniquely labeling members of the same cluster. Do you know how to perform operations like determining the maximum, minimum and average size of the clusters, the maximum, minimum average number of individuals in the clusters and finally the maximum, minimum average inter-cluster distance?

Comment: Max, min and mean number of individuals in clusters is easy: `max map length clusters`, `min map length clusters` and `mean map length clusters` should do it. Inter-cluster distance is trickier, because it could be defined in different ways. Do you want the distance between clusters' centers? Between the closest turtles in each cluster? I'd suggest you ask a separate question for that and try to be precise about what you need.

Comment: Wow dbsan is awesome, the extension you designed, "dist" is also amazing. I am guessing I just replace max or mean or min in any of those functions with count, to get the number of clusters. How do I get the mean, max and min size (radial extent or furthest distance between any two members of the same cluster)? And yes, I meant the distance between cluster centers for the max, min and mean inter-cluster distance.

Comment: The number of clusters is just `count clusters`. Radial extent would be something like: `to-report radial-extent [ cluster ]
  report max map [ a ->
    max map [ b -> [ distance a ] of b ] cluster
  ] cluster
end`. Once you have this, you can do `mean map radial-extent clusters` and so on. Cluster centers can be more or less tricky depending on your world's topology. Do you have horizontal or vertical world wrapping turned on?

Comment: (This really should have been separate questions. This is getting too long for comments... :-) )

Comment: the world is vertically wrapped!

Comment: using `count clusters` generated the following error: `count expected input to be an agent set but got a list`. any thoughts?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should have been `length clusters`. (`count` is for agentsets, `length` is for lists. In this case, `clusters` is a list so you need to use `length`. Sometimes I mix them up.)

Comment: in the `to-report radial-extent [ cluster ]` function code, a similar error comes up in relation to the line `... distance a ] of b ...` with thte use of the `of` operator, and it says that `OF expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the list`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Nicholas, in the `to-report radial-extent [ cluster ]` function code, a similar error comes up in relation to the line `... distance a ] of b ...` with thte use of the of operator, and it says that `OF expected input to be an agent or agentset but got the list`. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Comment: You're probably passing it your whole list of clusters. You need to pass it an *individual* cluster. For example: `print map radial-extent clusters`, or `foreach clusters [ c -> print radial-extent c ]`, or `print first clusters`, etc.

Comment: I think the problem is with the report function you gave me that produces the cluster radial extent itself: `to-report radial-extent [ cluster ]
  report max map [
    a -> max map [
      b -> [
        distance a ] of b
    ]
    cluster
  ]
  cluster
end` The operator `of` in the function is treating the distance as a list instead of an agent set! I don't know if a print statement fixes it.

Comment: The `radial-extent` reporter works fine if you pass it what it expects, which is a single cluster consisting of a list of turtles. I would need to see exactly how you are trying to use it to figure out why it does not work for you, but this would warrant a separate question.